# How do I change an element in a nested list?

Tags: python, tuples, coordinates, nested-lists, points

I am a Python beginner and in need of some advice.

I defined ten variables that all have an X and Y value.

Then I put these variables (which are actually a list) in another list called "pointlist".

Now, I want to use a **for-loop to change the X-value of each variable**.

Usually, I can access the X-value of the first variable through "pointlist[0][0]".

When I applied this to the for-loop I got the following error:
"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple"

Does anyone have an idea what I missed? Thank you so much in advance!

```
import random 
X=1350
Y=250

p1=[X, Y]
p2=[X, Y]
p3=[X, Y]
p4=[X, Y]
p5=[X, Y]
p6=[X, Y]
p7=[X, Y]
p8=[X, Y]
p9=[X, Y]
p10=[X, Y]
p11=[X, Y]
pointlist = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11]

limit1=1150
limit2=1250

for i in enumerate (pointlist, start=1):
    pointlist[i][0] = random.randrange(limit1, limit2)
    limit1-=100
    limit2-=100
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pythonize your loop using:

```
for i in pointlist:
    i[0] = random.randrange(limit1, limit2)
    limit1-=100
    limit2-=100
```

This way `i` becomes an entry of `pointlist` for easy access

Answer (score 2):

you might want to use `range` instead of `enumerate`.

```
import random 
X=1350
Y=250

p1=[X, Y]
p2=[X, Y]
p3=[X, Y]
p4=[X, Y]
p5=[X, Y]
p6=[X, Y]
p7=[X, Y]
p8=[X, Y]
p9=[X, Y]
p10=[X, Y]
p11=[X, Y]
pointlist = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11]

limit1=1150
limit2=1250

for i in range(len(pointlist)):
    pointlist[i][0] = random.randrange(limit1, limit2)
    limit1-=100
    limit2-=100
```

if you still want to use **enumerate**.

```
import random 
X=1350
Y=250

p1=[X, Y]
p2=[X, Y]
p3=[X, Y]
p4=[X, Y]
p5=[X, Y]
p6=[X, Y]
p7=[X, Y]
p8=[X, Y]
p9=[X, Y]
p10=[X, Y]
p11=[X, Y]
pointlist = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11]

limit1=1150
limit2=1250

for i in enumerate(pointlist, start=0):
    index = i[0] # get the index from here.
    value = i[1]
    pointlist[index][0] = random.randrange(limit1, limit2)
    limit1-=100
    limit2-=100
```

Answer (score 2):

The `enumerate` call returns a tuple on each loop, not a single value. So, your `i` is being set to a tuple, which consists of the index (starting at 1) and the element in the pointlist. You can fix this many ways. One is to change:

```
for i in enumerate(pointlist, start=1):
```

to:

```
for i in range(len(pointlist), start=1):
```

Or you can keep the `enumerate` call and drop the returned element of `pointlist`, which doesn't really make much sense, but it's an option:

```
for i, _ in enumerate(pointlist, start=1):
```

Here, the `_` is a placeholder that takes the pointlist value to prevent `i` from being a tuple. The first option is much better.

Note that list indeces start at 0, not 1, so you're `start=1` is probably going to break your logic. You might be much better off with the default start value of 0.

Answer (score 2):

**Off-topic.**

Adding to Mat's amazing answer:

I believe you explicitly created `p1`...`p11` so when you change the x-coordinate of a point, other points will not be affected. If you are not going to use the references `p1`...`p11`, I suggest using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
point_list = [[X, Y] for _ in range(11)]
```

The inner list `[X, Y]` is created 11 times, and they are 11 separate objects, so changing any one of it will not affect the others. You can visualise it using [Python Tutor](https://pythontutor.com).

I personally prefer using custom objects than dealing with nested lists in your case, as it better displays the intent of the code. Here is how I would  have coded it:

```py
import random

class Coordinate:
    """
    A container that represents a coordinate point.
    Functions to manipulate the coordinates (called methods)
    can be added here.
    You can optionally convert it to a dataclass using
    functools.dataclass decorator to clean up the code further.
    """

    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float) -> None:
        """ At creation of the Coordinate object,
        we set its x, y-coordinate values. """
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        """ Defines how a Coordinate should be represented as a string."""
        return f'Coordinate({self.x}, {self.y})'

X = 1350
Y = 250

coords = [Coordinate(X, Y) for _ in range(11)]

lower_bound = 1150
upper_bound = 1250

for coord in coords:
    # Here we are saying we want to change the x-coordinate,
    # instead of the ambiguous coord[0] = ...
    coord.x = random.randrange(1150, 1250)
    lower_bound -= 100
    upper_bound -= 100

print(coords)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Although it's off-topic you actually helped me with a totally different problem I was having! I appreciate it! Best reagrds.